# Specify target-queues in Messages

Tags: spring-amqp

I'm using Spring-AMQP for communication between some services. Inside the services I'm declaring consumers. One queue per consumer is used to dispatch the corresponding messages. A consumer-manager holds all known consumers. The actual message dispatching runs over a message-handler, which looks up for consumers subscribing the corresponding message-types. In almost any use-case a service subscribes a message only with one consumer.

For a special case I have to distinct not only the message-types but also the queue, from where the message is coming from.

Is is possible to retrieve somehow the queue name, from which the message was read?

Comment: I don't believe so, but if you have one consumer per queue, don't you implicitly know which consumer forwards the message to the handler?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. A colleague of mine posted the same issue on spring-forum. I refere to the post because the discussion is advanced there. Thanks a lot. [http://forum.springsource.org/](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?138897-Handing-incoming-messages&p=448716#post448716)